# Null pointer exception on insert method for sqlite database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm creating a sports team android application for a University project and I am having a little trouble with my database. I am trying to add a fixture to the database but I am getting the following nullpointer exception when I click on the 'Add' button.

```
12-27 16:40:29.420    6977-6977/com.example.myacer.clubhub E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.example.myacer.clubhub.Manager.UpdateSchedule$1.onClick(UpdateSchedule.java:54)
                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4262)
                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17421)
                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4944)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The error is at line 54 in the UpdateSchedule class. Line 54 is the

```
dbHelper.insertFixture
```

Here is the rest of my UpdateSchedule class where the manager of the team can add a fixture

```
public class UpdateSchedule extends AppCompatActivity {

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    EditText match_date;
    EditText match_time;
    EditText match_opponent;
    EditText match_venue;
    Button btnAdd;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_updateschedule);

        match_date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureDateEdit);
        match_time = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureTimeEdit);
        match_opponent = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureOpponentEdit);
        match_venue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fixtureVenueEdit);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addFixtureButton);

        addFixture();

    }

    public void addFixture() {
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        dbHelper.insertFixture(
                                match_date.getText().toString(),
                                match_time.getText().toString(),
                                match_opponent.getText().toString(),
                                match_venue.getText().toString());


                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

This is my DBHelper class.

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String LOG = "DatabaseHelper";

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "clubhub.db";

    private static final String TABLE_FIXTURES = "fixtures";

    private static final String TABLE_DIARY = "diary";

    private static final String TABLE_NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    private static final String TABLE_USERS = "users";

    //common column names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String PLAYER_NAME = "player_name";

    //fixtures table columns
    private static final String MATCH_DATE = "match_date";
    private static final String MATCH_TIME = "match_time";
    private static final String MATCH_OPPONENT = "match_opponent";
    private static final String MATCH_VENUE = "match_venue";

    //diary table columns
    private static final String SLEEP_LENGTH = "sleep_length";
    private static final String SLEEP_QUALITY = "sleep_quality";
    private static final String ENERGY = "energy";
    private static final String MOOD = "mood";
    private static final String APPETITE = "appetite";
    private static final String WATER_INTAKE = "water_intake";
    private static final String SORENESS = "soreness";
    private static final String WORKOUT_TYPE = "workout_type";
    private static final String WORKOUT_LENGTH = "workout_length";
    private static final String WORKOUT_RPE = "workout_rpe";

    //notification table columns
    private static final String MESSAGE = "message";

    //user table columns
    private static final String PASSWORD = "password";

    //table create statements

    //table fixtures create
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_FIXTURES = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FIXTURES
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + MATCH_DATE + " DATETIME,"
            + MATCH_TIME + " DATETIME NOT NULL,"
            + MATCH_OPPONENT + " TEXT,"
            + MATCH_VENUE + " TEXT"
            + ")";

    //table diary create
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_DIARY = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_DIARY
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + SLEEP_LENGTH + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + SLEEP_QUALITY + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + ENERGY + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + MOOD + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + APPETITE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + WATER_INTAKE + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + SORENESS + " INTEGER NOT NULL,"
            + WORKOUT_TYPE + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
            + WORKOUT_LENGTH + " DATETIME NOT NULL,"
            + WORKOUT_RPE + " INTEGER NOT NULL"
            + ")";

    //table notification create
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE_NOTIFICATION = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NOTIFICATION
            + "(" + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + MESSAGE + " TEXT NOT NULL"
            + ")";


    /**
     * constructor with args
     */
    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_FIXTURES);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_DIARY);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NOTIFICATION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FIXTURES);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_DIARY);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NOTIFICATION);

        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertFixture(String date, String time, String opponent, String venue){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MATCH_DATE, date);
        values.put(MATCH_TIME, time);
        values.put(MATCH_OPPONENT, opponent);
        values.put(MATCH_VENUE, venue);

        long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_FIXTURES, null, values);

        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

The insert method looks like

```
public boolean insertFixture(String date, String time, String opponent, String venue){
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MATCH_DATE, date);
    values.put(MATCH_TIME, time);
    values.put(MATCH_OPPONENT, opponent);
    values.put(MATCH_VENUE, venue);

    long result = sqLiteDatabase.insert(TABLE_FIXTURES, null, values);

    if (result == -1) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: where are your `dbHelper` instance ?

Comment: dbHelper = new DBHelper (this); add this line inside onCreate.

Comment: and add `private DBHelper dbHelper` as global;

Comment: thanks guys, rookie mistake

Answer (score 1):

you have not created instance for DBHelper in UpdateSchedule . Without creating an instance for DBHelper you are trying to invoke the methods on it.